# How to input array of chars in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a 2d array like below

```
---
-m-
p--
```

How to input those into array without just with?
I know nextInt(), nextLine() but those won't help me in this problem?

here is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = in.nextInt();
    char[][] board = new char[n][n];
    for(int i=0 ; i<n ; i++){
        for(int j=0 ; j<n ;j++){
            board[i][j] = //problem at here

        }
    }
```

Comment: What? Show at least *some* code! Or add a lot more explanation. Input from where? Are you talking about a command line application?

Comment: Show what you tried; `nextInt()` shouldn't help, but `nextLine()` might work if used properly.

Comment: @ScottHunter nextLine() is good but I have to cast string to char. is there any better solution?

Comment: @ScottHunter I just wanted to say I know them.

Comment: You cant simply cast a string as a char array unfortunately, but the charAt() method makes the job of converting them easy enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `nextLine()` you can use `charAt(index)` to get each individual char.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = in.nextInt();
    char[][] board = new char[n][n];
    for(int i=0 ; i<n ; i++){
        String line = in.nextLine();
        for(int j=0 ; j<n ;j++){
            board[i][j] = line.charAt(j);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're asking for an array of characters, in which case you have part of the solution but not the whole thing.

The key would be to use nextLine() to get a line, and then use a loop to get each char and store it in the array (we're going to assume that the lines are of a fixed length for thing implementation).

I'm going to skip the work of finding the number of lines in the file, that I'll leave up to you.

```
/* used to set the size of the 2d array*/
FileReader reader = new FileReader("filename");
BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
int numLines = getNumLines(file);
int lineLength = getLengthLines(file); 

char[][] map = new char[numLines][lineLength]
for(int i = 0; i<numLines; i++){
    String currentLine = bReader.nextLine();
    for(int x = 0; x<lineLength; i++)
        map[i][x] = currentLine.charAt(x);
    }
}
```

Be sure to comment if you have any other questions!

References for [reading in a file](https://www.caveofprogramming.com/java/java-file-reading-and-writing-files-in-java.html) in Java.